# How to share one dialog window for loading different data across multiple child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of learning react, and converting all my classes into functional components with hooks.

I have a main dashboard that shows a list of tiles/cards, and each card is able to bring up the same dialog window for editing but with different data.

[image]

The way I have achieved this currently is that I have a component that maps an array of items and each item have a child card component with its own dialog window. **I was wondering if it is possible to reuse a common dialog window component by passing different data upon opening the window so it can be shared.**

Parent component

```js
public render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/* Opens the same edit window for creating new workout */}
                <AddWorkoutButton updateWorkout={this.updateWorkouts} isDarkMode={this.props.isDarkMode}/>
                <div className="container" style={{paddingBottom: '3rem'}}>
                    <div className="row">
                        {/* Create individual card for each workout */}
                            {this.state.workoutData.map((workoutData: object, index: number) =>
                            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={index}>

                                {/* Create each card as child component */}
                                <WorkoutCard workoutData={workoutData} updateWorkout={this.updateWorkouts} isDarkMode={this.props.isDarkMode}/>

                            </div>
                            )}  
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Child component (Card)

```js
public render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {/* Inside edit window contains a dialog component */}
        <EditWindow
        openEditWindow={this.state.openEditWindow} 
        handleClose={this.handleClose}
        updateWorkout={this.props.updateWorkout}
        isDarkMode={this.props.isDarkMode}
        workoutData={this.props.workoutData}
        />
        
        <Card className={classes.card}>
        ...
        <Card/>
      </div> 
    )
  }
```

Edit window (dialog component that I wish to share instead of generating for each child component)
Note: this component I have converted to a functional component with hooks (not sure if that affects anything)

```js
return (
        <div>
            {/* parent components will invoke the edit window/dialog */}
            <Dialog
                maxWidth={"md"}
                fullWidth
                open={props.openEditWindow}
                // onEnter={openWorkoutDialog}
                TransitionComponent={Transition}
                onClose={() => {setWorkoutData(props.workoutData); props.handleClose()}}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
            >
            ...
            </Dialog>
```

Finally, with react dev tools we can see that each workout card has its own edit window

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the `EditWindow` component inside of you parent to achieve what you want. Then you can have state in you parent component that holds the `workoutData` that should be edited in the modal.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    workoutData: null
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddWorkoutButton
          updateWorkout={this.updateWorkouts}
          isDarkMode={this.props.isDarkMode}
        />
        <div className="container" style={{ paddingBottom: "3rem" }}>
          <div className="row">
            {/* Create individual card for each workout */}
            {this.state.workoutData.map(
              (workoutData: object, index: number) => (
                <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={index}>
                  {/* Create each card as child component */}
                  <WorkoutCard
                    workoutData={workoutData}
                    updateWorkout={this.updateWorkouts}
                    isDarkMode={this.props.isDarkMode}
                    editWorkoutData={() =>
                      this.setState({ workoutData: workoutData })
                    }
                  />
                </div>
              )
            )}
          </div>
          <EditWindow
            openEditWindow={this.state.workoutData !== null}
            handleClose={() => this.setState({ workoutData: null })}
            updateWorkout={this.props.updateWorkout}
            isDarkMode={this.props.isDarkMode}
            workoutData={this.state.workoutData}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class WorkoutCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card className={classes.card} onClick={this.props.editWorkoutData}>...</Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function EditWindow(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        maxWidth={"md"}
        fullWidth
        open={props.openEditWindow}
        // onEnter={openWorkoutDialog}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        onClose={() => {
          setWorkoutData(props.workoutData);
          props.handleClose();
        }}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi if I were to do this then I would also need to somehow let edit window know which card I'm opening up to then load the data?

I also tried putting edit window inside the map but that just generates multiple edit windows. It also is a bit more problematic as all the edit windows opens for some reason.

Comment: @Hilkjh, yes you would need state in your parent component to hold the workoutData that should be updated. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions above; however, the data is loaded after the window closes. Anywhere this might be happening?

Comment: Yes, that is because of the `setWorkoutData(props.workoutData);` in the `onClose` prop of the `Dialog` component.

Comment: On the view and edit button i added this onClick

onClick={() => {console.log(currentWorkoutData); setCurrentWorkoutData(workoutData); console.log(currentWorkoutData);}

It appears that the setting data does not update immediately? I don't know why.

Comment: Consider creating a minimal reproducible example in a sandbox environment so we can better help you out.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-goldstine-gvvw4?file=/src/Workouts.tsx

Comment: Hey @Robert, I have fixed this in EditWindow by adding onEnter={() => {setWorkoutData(props.workoutData)}}. Let me know if this is a poor approach or not. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that is a good approach. You need to reset your state everytime you re-open your modal and that will do it for you. For what it's worth, I also got your sandbox working: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-modal-react-state-biy5b

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple approach would be to use a Dialog component that renders itself into the parent "root" of your application with a react-portal. This Dialog might update whenever the parent that manages your cards is updating its state giving some configuration like "open", "text", "heading" etc. to the Dialog component via props.

Take a look at this solution: https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-simple-modal-component-with-react-16decdc111a6

Comment: Hey is it more appropriate/conventional to do this with react portals instead of what Robert has mentioned below?

Comment: Hey, i can't tell you if this is conventional. Some Advantages are: it's easy to implement and you can use your dialog component from anywere. Disadvantages might be that you always need to change the dialog-config and you might forget about changing the header or something like that. Btw. it's the same way as robert mentions in his answer.